# iOS view component but can't find correct name for it

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, components

I'm looking for ready to use (can be paid) view component for iOS that looks like calendar day view but the day can show me events per persons or workplaces so I can see on one view when there is a free gap so I can make an appointment for this workplace. Imagine we are the dentist salon and we have 3 workplaces. We need a view that will help us to see is that workplace actually busy or free and we need this only per day. Currently in iOS Calendar We are able to see only events for one workplace but we need to add another column for second workplace and so on for a particular day. What to look for in google? What phrases can be useful to find such component?

```
|                Monday 10.05.2015             |
------------------------------------------------
|   Time   |   Workplace 1   |   Workplace 2   |
|   7:00   |                 |   Cleaning      |
|   8:00   |   Mr. Brux      |                 |
|   9:00   |                 |   Mr. Griffin   |
|  10:00   |   Cleaning      |                 |
|  11:00   |                 |   Mrs. Boxa     |
|  12:00   |                 |                 |
|  13:00   |   Mr. Bravo     |   Mr. Cabad     |
|  14:00   |                 |                 |
|  15:00   |                 |                 |
|  16:00   |                 |                 |
```